# how to put php string jQuery validation error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation to validate a form the js code looks like this:

```
form.validate({
        messages: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: "<?php echo Translation::tr('profileform.error.yearsOfExperience');?>"
            }
        },
        rules: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: [0, 100]
            }
        }
});
```

Translation::tr('profileform.error.yearsOfExperience') ->  makes a simple mysql call to the database and returns a string (the error message for the element) but the problem is that i can't display the error message (i get blank).

if i change the javasctipt code like this it works just fine:

```
form.validate({
        messages: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: "Please select a number from 0 to 100"
            }
        },
        rules: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: [0, 100]
            }
        }
});
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want messages from PHP code ?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around the php code tell javascsript it's just a string nothing is interpreting it.
Try

```
    form.validate({
        messages: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: <?php echo json_encode( Translation::tr('profileform.error.yearsOfExperience') ); ?>;
            }
        },
        rules: {
            years_of_experience: {
                range: [0, 100]
            }
        }
   });
```

It's ugly... but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The original question has almost nothing to do with jQuery Validate and everything to do with PHP, since the page is constructed by the PHP long before any JavaScript evaluates it.  The proper way to troubleshoot this would be to look at the source code in the browser to see where your PHP is going wrong and adjust is accordingly.  As long as you see a string, jQuery Validate would be using that string.

---

HOWEVER, based on the desired message, you would not need any PHP at all.  This plugin will automatically insert parameters from the `rules` into the `messages`.  The first parameter is represented by `{0}` and the second is represented by `{1}`, etc.

```
messages: {
    years_of_experience: {
        range: "Please select a number from {0} to {1}"
    }
},
rules: {
    years_of_experience: {
        range: [0, 100]  // <- parameters
    }
}
```

Result:

> Please select a number from 0 to 100

Comment: I changed the extension of the javasctipt file to a .php file. Now the problem is that i don't include the required yii classes to call this call function . (That pfp file is outside the yii protected folders...)

Comment: @MikeSiakovellis, Did you miss the point of my answer?  If you use the parameter placeholders like I've shown, you won't need to depend on any PHP to construct this piece of JavaScript.

Comment: I want to put a dynamic php string into thew range error message

Comment: @MikeSiakovellis, what is the purpose of that when the actual range is not dynamic, but ***fixed*** by the JavaScript, `[0,100]`?